# Correct way to store and retrieve +2000 List items Sharepojnt 2007

Tags: c#, performance, sharepoint, recursion, sharepoint-2007

So I've read all the whitepapers, and I know that you can store up to 5 million list items in a list as long as you use folders.

What I'm after, is, has anyone written some nice recursion that gets a list, looks at all the folders in the list, and assigns list items either to a <2000 folder, or creates a new folder if one does not exist?

Same thing with list item retrival. Does anyone have a nice clean and fast method for getting all list items from a list 2000 at a time?

I've looked on google and here and haven't found a nice definitive guide for storing and retrieving list items from large lists with code samples, it's all been about the theory from what I can see.

Comment: Any chance to use 2010? Supports large lists more directly (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx)...

Comment: Sadly, no. This is for a client, and upgrades are not on the table.

Comment: You can store more than 2000 items in the same list (without folders) what really impacts sharepoint performance is retrieving more than 2000 items in a single view, or API call. So just make sure that you are using reasonable filters to limit the results to 2000 items or fewer.

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is to tell a client that doing this isn't an appropriate use of the technology. You'll end up with a compromised viewing and filtering system and it'll be combersome to use. Use the BDC instead.

Comment: @EtherDragon you should post that as an answer, because that's the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store more than 2000 items in the same list (without folders) what really impacts sharepoint performance is retrieving more than 2000 items in a single view, or API call. So just make sure that you are using reasonable filters to limit the results to 2000 items or fewer.

I have crafted WSS Solutions that rely on ~10,000 list entries per year, but we were just very careful that our CAML Query or API call limited results to 2000 items or fewer, at a time.